# Terraform aws_iam_access_key secret in another division (using remote_state)

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform infrastructure that is divided into "parts" that looks something like this.

```
.
├── network
│   ├── locals.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── ecs
│   ├── locals.tf
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── outputs.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── sqs
    ├── locals.tf
    ├── main.tf
    ├── output.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

In SQS, I'm creating a programmatic user with `aws_iam_user` and `aws_iam_access_key`.

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "sqs_write" {
  name = "sqs-queue-name-read"
  path = "/system/"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "sqs_write" {
  user    = aws_iam_user.sqs_write.name
  pgp_key = local.settings.gpg_public_key
}
```

Now I need to be able to use `aws_iam_access_key.sqs_write.secret` in my ECS division.

I tried sending the secret to an "output" and use it with `data.terraform_remote_state` in my ECS division but Terraform says the output does not exist (most likely because it is marked as `sensitive = true`.

I tried to save the `aws_iam_access_key.sqs_write.secret` to a SSM parameter with:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "write_secret" {
  name        = "sqs-queue-name-write-secret-access-key"
  description = "SQS write secret access key"
  key_id      = "aws/secretsmanager"
  type        = "String"
  value       = aws_iam_access_key.sqs_write.secret
  overwrite   = true
}
```

But I get this error:

```
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   with aws_ssm_parameter.write_secret,
│   on main.tf line 109, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "write_secret":
│  109:   value       = aws_iam_access_key.sqs_write.secret
│
│ The argument "value" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
```

So I can't seem to find a way to use the "secret" value outside of my SQS division. I could use the "encrypted_secret" version of it that works fine, but I don't know how I could decrypt it directly from Terraform so I guess it is not an option.

Any thoughts?

My version is:

> Terraform v1.0.2 on linux_amd64
>
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.52.0
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/http v2.1.0

Comment: Why do you want to use an IAM user with ECS? Are you aware of [IAM roles for ECS tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)? This will have AWS automatically manage credentials and their rotation and is preferable to using IAM users which instead should be for running things off AWS (eg users accessing the console or API from a desktop or an application that runs in another cloud or on premise that needs to access an AWS resource).

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I need it because this is how the application was developed. I would have preferred a role indeed. But this is not how the architect designed it and not how the application was developed, unfortunately.

Comment: You can just remove any reference to loading access keys and allow the AWS SDK to automatically use the ECS provided IAM role instead. It should be like a couple of lines change if you have access to the source code and will solve a _lot_ of other issues.

Comment: Also instead of passing things around using the remote state data source you should instead look at first class ways of doing this such as with the [`aws_ssm_parameter` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter). That will solve any issues with trying to use the slightly fickle remote state data source. I'd still strongly advise ditching the IAM keys though.

Comment: I will check with the architect and the dev team to see if they can change that. But as for ssm, I already tried that (as mentioned in the question) but I face the same issue. Terrafom seems to block me from putting the secret in the ssm parameter value.